# How to build GUI application in C language using GTK+?

Tags: gtk, programming, gcc, c

I have written code in C language using GTK. This code gives a window with 2 buttons, but I do not know how to make the standalone GUI application from this code.

Please explain to me step by step and in detail.

```c
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
void static call(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data)
{
    g_print("%s \n",(gchar*) data);
}

int main(int agrc, char *agrv[])
{
    gtk_init(&agrc,&agrv);
    GtkWidget *window,*button,*vbox;
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"two button");

    vbox=gtk_vbox_new(0,0);
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("button 1");
    g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),(gpointer) "BUTTON 1");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),button,0,0,0);
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("button 2");
    g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),(gpointer) "BUTTON 2");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),button,0,0,0);
    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("Close");
    g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(call),(gpointer) "BUTTON 2");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),button,0,0,0);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox); 
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the `libgtk2.0-dev` package in the normal way from the repository, then you can build your application with `gcc`, using `pkg-config` to set the appropriate include and library directives e.g.

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

For more information see the [GTK+ 2.0 Tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/) at the [Gnome Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/)

Comment: this command works fine and creates .exe file for simple c code without any `#include<gtk/gtk.h` in the c code              `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc code.c -o code` but when i try to compile c code with `#include<gtk/gtk.h` using the following command it gives me error 
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc code.c -o code `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`